# how do I make this query work mysql 5.5.20 two tables with rank function

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have Two Tables

Students Table

| id | adminno | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p001 | john |
| 2 | p002 | Jane |
| 3 | p003 | Jack |
| 4 | p004 | Joan |

Marks table

| id | adminno | term | year | marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p001 | Term I | 2021 | 300 |
| 2 | p002 | Term I | 2021 | 400 |
| 3 | p003 | Term I | 2021 | 200 |
| 4 | P004 | Term I | 2021 | 700 |

Expected Results

| id | adminno | fullname | term | year | marks | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | p004 | Joan | Term I | 2021 | 700 | 1 |
| 2 | p002 | Jane | Term I | 2021 | 400 | 2 |
| 1 | p001 | john | Term I | 2021 | 300 | 3 |
| 3 | P003 | Jack | Term I | 2021 | 200 | 4 |

my Code

```
   SET @curRank := 0;
   SELECT 
    students.adminno,
    students.fullname,
    students.id,
    students.adminno,
    marks.term,
    marks.year,
    marks.total as total,
    rank FROM
    (SELECT
    students.adminno,
    students.fullname,
    students.id,
    marks.adminno,
    marks.id,
    marks.term,
    marks.year,
    marks.total as total,
    @curRank := IF(@prevRank = total, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank, 
    @incRank := @incRank + 1, 
    @prevRank := total
    FROM marks p, (
    SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1 )r
    INNER JOIN students.adminno =marks.adminno 
    WHERE students.term='Term I'
    ORDER BY total DESC ) s;
```

I'm getting this Error

> ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

How Do I join the two tables correctly to get my desired results.
I'm a beginner in mysql

Comment: MySQL 5.5.20 there is allias problem in joining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT total.*, @rank := @rank + 1 AS student_rank
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM marks 
       JOIN students USING (id, adminno) ) total
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) variable
ORDER BY total.marks DESC;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc74b343be4722352c1a193bf2a709ea

Comment: Thanks it worked is there any way I can display specific fields

Comment: @ANTHONYMWANGI Of course. Replace `SELECT total.*` with definite columns list. Or maybe replace `SELECT *` in the subquery.

Comment: I tried but the results Changed no names when I repalced SELECT * in subquery with select id,adminno,term,marks.inthe results names get lost

Comment: @ANTHONYMWANGI Subquery has 2 tables in its rowsource, so you must specify table alias for each column in the output list. *in the results names get lost* You skip `names` column in subquery output list. Only columns speciified in subquery output are available in outer query.

Comment: Its is working but incase of a tie it has a problem

Comment: @ANTHONYMWANGI Think a little. Gather all possible source data combinations which may occur in source data and needs in special inperpretation. Open my fiddle, edit its INSERT INTO and add your source data. Provide the link to edited fiddle and desired output for your data with detailed explanations about what is not correct in current query output (put this everything into your question as an update).